# How to enable sorting on a protected worksheet in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, sorting, protected, vba

Hi  I'm new to VBA but have found numerous answers here to queries before, but there's one issue I can't resolve.  I've managed to enable outlining and filtering but can't get the code correct to enable sorting on unprotected cells within a sheet.  The code I have so far, which works exactly how required, is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    For Each ws In Sheets
        With ws
            .Unprotect Password:="password"

            .Protect Password:="password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

            .EnableOutlining = True
            .EnableAutoFilter = True
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

I've tried `EnableSort = True`, `EnableSorting = True` but neither works.  The code is within the Visual Basic and not a Macro (I hope this makes sense)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: When in doubt, record a macro and amend it :)

Comment: You do not need to `.Unprotect` first - just do `.Protect Contents:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowSorting:=True`. Note that `Contents:=True` must be stated if `.Protect` is done without unprotecting first (at least in some cases, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57679094/1349511)). Note that the parameter `AllowSorting:=True` only enables sorting for unlocked cells (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.protection.allowsorting)); the cells containing the headings of the sort area also need to be unlocked.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
```

Comment: Sorry didnt see your reply.. deleted my post :)

Comment: Unfortunately I get a compile error if I try and add this to the code.

Comment: Did you add the parameters this way `.Unprotect Password:="password", AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True`?