# Worksheet.Protection Contents defaults to FALSE after calling Worksheet.Protect twice

Tags: excel, vba

The `Contents` parameter of the `Worksheet.Protect` method is `TRUE` by default ([Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect)). Debugging my code I found that the `ProtectContents` property falls to `FALSE` if `Worksheet.Protect` is called again on an already protected sheet under certain circumstances. I do not understand why; is this a desired behaviour?

Here's the code I use:

```
Sheets(1).Protect _
    Userinterfaceonly:=True, _
    DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Password:=MyPassword
' calling twice => ProtectContents falls to FALSE !
```

If I leave out the `DrawingObjects` parameter, then `ProtedctContents` remains `TRUE` after calling the code twice:

```
Sheets(1).Protect _
    Userinterfaceonly:=True, _
    Password:=MyPassword
' calling twice => ProtectContents remains TRUE
```

=> If the `Protect` method is called on an already protected sheet giving any parameter, the behaviour differs from calling `Protect` on an unprotected sheet?

My solution is to add `Contents:=True` explicitly:

```
Sheets(1).Protect _
    Contents:=True, _
    Userinterfaceonly:=True, _
    DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Password:=MyPassword
' calling twice => ProtectContents remains TRUE as stated
```

So I already know how to get my code to work, but I'd like to clearly understand the reason why.