# Locking/Unlocking cell based on value of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have a cell lock/unlock depending on the value of another cell. I'll call the cell I want to lock "Data_Cell" and the cell whose value determines whether or not it should be locked "Permission_Cell". I am trying to accomplish this via Worksheet_Change:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  
    Application.EnableEvents = False
  
    .Unprotect Password:=""
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("Permission_Cell")) Is Nothing Then
      If .Range("Permission_Cell").Value = "No" Then
        .Range("Data_Cell").Formula = "=Some_Other_Named_Range"
        .Range("Data_Cell").Locked = True
      Else
        .Range("Data_Cell").Locked = False
      End If
    End If
    
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  .Protect Password:="", AllowFiltering:=True, AllowSorting:=True, UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, DrawingObjects:=True
    
  End With
  
End Sub
```

Note that Permission_Cell is unlocked and can be changed between Yes/No. When Permission_Cell says "No", then Data_Cell should have the formula "=Some_Other_Named_Range" and should be locked. Otherwise, Data_Cell should be unlocked and able to be edited.

When I implement this and enter "No" in Permission_Cell, Excel indicates that the sheet is protected and that Data_Cell is locked (note the padlock icon is highlighted). However, I am still allowed to enter a different value in Data_Cell. If I click "Unprotect Sheet" and then "Protect Sheet", then Data_Cell is properly locked. Why is the locking via VBA not working?

[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Don't you have `Option Explicit` on top of the sheet module? There is a typo in `If Not Intersect(rng, .Range("Permission Cell")) Is Nothing Then`. "Permission Cell" instead of "Permission_Cell". Is it a copying mistake? Does your code raise an error? IF yes, what error and on which code line? If not, what does it do against what you want it doing? Are you sure that you know what a `Change` event is and where its code must stay? It should be `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` and must exist in the code module of the sheet to be processed.

Comment: @FaneDuru Apologies, the typo is not in my actual VBA code though - I fixed it to include the underscore. "Not working" means what I described - running "Range("Data_Cell").Locked = False" and protecting the worksheet does not actually prevent me from changing Data_Cell. Adding "Option Explicit" does not fix the issue. There is no error raised.

Comment: **Where** the shown code exists? In the respective sheet code module, or in a standard module? `Option Explicit` only oblige you to declare all variables and warn in case of a  not declared one...

Comment: My Worksheet_Change sub exists in the code module of the sheet. Naming the parameter "Target" instead of "rng" has no impact (but I will note that it does not have to be named "Target" in general). You should be able to reproduce this yourself by copying and pasting the code I provided.

Comment: Are you sure that events are enabled? Try a simple sub containing only a single line: `Application.EnableEvents = True` and run it. After that, place a break point on the line `If Not Intersect(rng, .Range("Permission_Cell")) Is Nothing Then` and see if the event is triggered when you change the cell you want it be triggered. Then run the code line by line pressing `F8` and see if it continue as you need.

Comment: Is "Sheet1" the sheet name where the respective range to trigger the event exists?

Comment: Thank you, those debugging tips helped me uncover an issue. Changing the formula for Data_Cell was triggering Worksheet_Change again before the line that locks the cell was called. I am now disabling events at the beginning and re-enabling at the end. It seems to be working as intended now.

Comment: It was good to do it, to avoid the event being triggered three times, but if something else than "Permission_Cell" would be changed, it shouldn't do anything. To do that, you should move `.Unprotect` ... `.Protect` inside the `If` ... `End If` statement...

Comment: Thank you. I only want it to trigger when Permission_Cell is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code exist in sheet's module then change the second line to: With Me

It works fine in my office2007

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  With Me
  
    Application.EnableEvents = False
  
    .Unprotect Password:=""
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("Permission_Cell")) Is Nothing Then
      If .Range("Permission_Cell").Value = "No" Then
        .Range("Data_Cell").Formula = "=Some_Other_Named_Range"
        .Range("Data_Cell").Locked = True
      Else
        .Range("Data_Cell").Locked = False
      End If
    End If
    
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  .Protect Password:="", AllowFiltering:=True, AllowSorting:=True, UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, DrawingObjects:=True
    
  End With
  
End Sub
```

Comment: It turns out that part of my problem was also related to this bug - if you protect a worksheet using VBA twice, then the contents become unprotected unless you specify "Contents:=True": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679094/worksheet-protection-contents-defaults-to-false-after-calling-worksheet-protect